# Can an empty ArrayField on Django Admin be saved?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

*models.py*

```py
class BlogArticle(models.Model):
    # ...
    likers = ArrayField(models.GenericIPAddressField(), default=list)
```

*admin.py*

```py
admin.site.register(BlogArticle)
```

When using Django Admin page for an article with an empty list, the input is empty. This is ok to me, but when saving the object (after editing other fields for example), I get this error:
[image]

It seems that it's interpreted as a `None` value, while to the current value is actually a valid empty list.

Why would Django use the same way to represent empty list and a None value in the admin? I'm wondering if it's poorly designed or if I'm missing something here.

Note that adding `blank=True` will make it worse, since it won't raise any error but will silently transform empty list to None.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I figured it out before posting but thought it could still be useful to others*

The simple (and maybe obvious to most of you) solution is:

`ArrayField(models.GenericIPAddressField(), default=list, blank=True, null=False)`